# UIKit: Constraints with respecting NavBar and ignoring safe area at the bottom

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uikit

I'm following by one of the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paMpdmJcpRg&t) of Paul Hudson and trying to recreate detail screen with full screen image. By following the video I set up constraints to `Reset to suggested contains` but I have different values compering to video. I tried to play around with settings but can't get the expected result...

**Constraints:**

```
Image View.top = topMargin - 44
Image View.centerX = centerX
Image View.centerY = centerY
Image View.leading = Safe Area.leading
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Expected:**

[image]

**Question:** How to set up constraints to respect NavigationBar and took all other place in the screen, like in expected image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your VC is embedded in a navigation controller, you basically want to constraint the left, right and bottom of the image view to be equal to its superview, and the top of the image view to the top layout guide:

[image]

You should select the image view, and add the constraints using this pop up:

[image]

Click on all four of the thingys I circled. If the first or second items of the constraints added are incorrect, change them by selecting the constraint and using the drop down here:

[image]

Alternatively, just add them with code:

```
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
    imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
    imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
    imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
])
```

Comment: In menus I don't have option Top Layout Guide (only SuperView and SafeArea). What need to do to add it or I do something wrong?

Comment: @Nizami  Choose Safe Area instead. It's probably because I have an older version of Xcode. :P If you can always do it with code if everything else fails. I'm pretty sure the code I presented will still work in iOS 16.

Comment: There are two options `Superview` and `Safe Area` in dropdown menu of Second Item when Image View.top is chosen (your third screen). When I choose `Superview` the image takes all space of the screen without respecting NavBar. `Safe Area` leaves white space on top but does't respect NavBar too(like in result image). Xcode Version 13.1 (13A1030d), iOS 15

Comment: Code that you presented works perfect but don't give me understandable how to achieve it using Storyboard, sry(

Comment: Finally achieved respect of NavBar by adding `Image View.top = Safe Area.top`

Comment: @Nizami Isn't that what I said? Choose Safe Area (instead of top layout guide). Also your Xcode version is interesting too. I'm using 13.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

Based on answer from [Sweeper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5133585/sweeper) created constraints in Storyboard:

```
Image View.leading = leading
Image View.top = Safe Area.top
trailing = Image View.trailing
bottom = Image View.bottom
```